# Enable audio seeking HTML5 audio and MediaElement.js players with PHP served source

Tags: mediaelement.js

I set up an MP3 audio player with MediaElement.js and it will not allow me to seek whereas the demo at mediaelementjs.com does allow seeking. I don't see any options or instruction about enabling seeking on the website. Why won't it seek?

I'm using version 2.13.1. Here is the code (except for the included js and css files):

```
<audio controls="control" preload="auto" src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<script>
$('audio').mediaelementplayer();
</script>
```

**Edit:** I found the problem to be how I served the audio file via PHP. I didn't mention this before, but I've changed the question title to include this. The MP3 file is being served via PHP readfile() in order to protect it from download by non-members.

Comment: Which browser are you using and can you see any error in the browser console?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: hmm, Chrome should be fine with mp3... Could you paste your code to jsfiddle.net?

Comment: What do you mean by seeking exactly? On your hen I click ahead on the time bar to say, 13:00, it works fine.

Comment: That is what I mean by seeking - clicking ahead on the time bar to go to another time in the audio. What is my "hen"?

Comment: I made a jsfiddle with a regular mp3 file as the source and it works. I think the problem is that in my actual private site I made the source as a page that forces the file download with Content-Type: application/octet-stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are serving your audio files via PHP for the HTML5 audio element and other players such as MediaElement.js, you need to include the following header for seeking to work:

```
<?php header('Accept-Ranges: bytes'); ?>
```

Here's my php to serve the file:

```
if(file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit();
}
```

Of course, you need to set $file (file path) and $filename (just the file name).

Comment: will readfile automatically seek to the point where the mediaelement.js wanted?

Comment: No, it will not. That's just some php to serve the file rather than hard linking to the actual file.

Comment: I am still trying to make MediaElement work.
I updated your code $filename = basename($file);
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");  sets the filename for download. It has to have quotes or if you have spaces in the file name only the first word will appear.